# Re-issue user id for participant

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'd like to re-issue enrollId for my participant of fabric composer 0.8.0.
so, firstly I've revoked my already issued id 'hanako'.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:~/git/composerPoCTool/tools/composer$ composer identity revoke -n "drive-manager-network" -i admin
-s Xurw3yU9zI0l -u hanako
```

The identity 'hanako' was revoked and can no longer be used to connect to the business network.
Command completed successfully.

Command succeeded

---

Next, I've issued  id 'hanako' one more time for my participant.
but I got 'User is already registered' Error...
Is there a way to re-issue for same id on fabric composer?

```
vagrant@ubuntu-1404:~/git/composerPoCTool/tools/composer$ composer identity issue -n "drive-manager-network" -i admin -
s Xurw3yU9zI0l -u hanako -a "org.denso.drive.Person#actorId:2"
```

Error: User is already registered
Command failed.

Command succeeded

Comment: I've have an answer on Rocket.chat.  -> once an id is issued it can never be reissued even if you revoke it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot re-use or re-issue ids -- this is a Fabric limitation.